Printing definition elements in an equation sequentially yields different lines
I'm trying to get a foreach block to print elements of a define dynamically and it's putting each element on a new line:

it should all be on one line like the following....

example code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,pgffor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{pgf,pgffor}

% % Define sequences
\def\S{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
\def\O{{0, 1, 0, 1, 0}}

\begin{document}
$\pi_0 \cdot b_0(0)$
\foreach \n in {1,...,4}  {%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prev}{\n-1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Sval}{\S[\n]}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\PrevSval}{\S[\prev]}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Oval}{\O[\n]}

    $\cdot$ $a_{\PrevSval\Sval}$ $\cdot$ $b_{\Sval}(\Oval)$%
} 
\end{document}


What I overlooked yesterday: You shouldn't define single-letter macros with \def (you shouldn't define anything you're not sure about using \def). \S for instance is already defined by LaTeX as the paragraph symbol §, and \O is the letter Ø.

Your \foreach includes a blank line. A blank line is the same as \par, so starts a new paragraph. Remove that blank line and stuff will end up on the same line. But then you'll notice that there is quite a lot of space between the items. That's caused by extra spaces (each line ending adds a space if TeX is not in a mode that ignores spaces like after a macro name), you can get rid of those using %.
Combined:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,pgffor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{pgf,pgffor}

% % Define sequences
\def\S{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
\def\O{{0, 1, 0, 1, 0}}

\begin{document}
$\pi_0 \cdot b_0(0)$% <- this removes the space at this line ending
\foreach \n in {1,...,4} { % <- this adds one space in front of each element
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prev}{\n-1}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Sval}{\S[\n]}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\PrevSval}{\S[\prev]}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Oval}{\O[\n]}%
    $\cdot$ $a_{\PrevSval\Sval}$ $\cdot$ $b_{\Sval}(\Oval)$%
} 
\end{document}


But if you want to get the correct spaces you should just put everything into the same inline math block (and since spaces are ignored inside of math you wouldn't have to worry as much about extraneous spaces):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,pgffor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{pgf,pgffor}

% % Define sequences
\def\S{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
\def\O{{0, 1, 0, 1, 0}}

\begin{document}
$\pi_0 \cdot b_0(0)
\foreach \n in {1,...,4} {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\prev}{\n-1}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Sval}{\S[\n]}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\PrevSval}{\S[\prev]}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Oval}{\O[\n]}%
    \cdot a_{\PrevSval\Sval} \cdot b_{\Sval}(\Oval)%
}$ 
\end{document}



Brilliant! thanks @Skillmon, works perfectly
